# How to change the process to another in setting

Tags: wi-fi, settings

The android I am working on is android version 9 after bypassing some built-in restricted settings in the watch(1). I came back to double-check in the "Network & Internet" setting, but it can't open the password input, it start to kick out and then it crashed. I check its log and It says:

> I/ActivityManager(  630): START u0 {act=com.zmapp.watch.wifi.input} from uid 1000, pid 9129

> I/ActivityManager(  630): ->startActivity for Intent { act=com.zmapp.watch.wifi.input } result:START_INTENT_NOT_RESOLVED

The `com.zmapp.watch.wifi.input` is a keyboard for the watch, it does not suppose to be here. It should look like this:

> I/ActivityManager(  630): START u0 {act=com.android.settings.action.SETTINGS_SEARCH pkg=com.android.settings.intelligence cmp=com.android.settings.intelligence/.search.SearchActivity} from uid 1000, pid 9553

> I/ActivityManager(  630): ->startActivity for ActivityRecord{c55f354 u0 com.android.settings.intelligence/.search.SearchActivity t71} result:START_SUCCESS

in the `act=` will be open the keyboard for wifi(2). Please tell me what process should be in it and how to do that?

---

**(1)** *The watch I'm currently working on can be found here "[link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/W5-children-s-smart-watch-4G_1600454103762.html)" the W5 one.*

**(2)** *The keyboard has a different layout for easier use because the original keyboard is too small for typing.*